# Activesupport gem complains that it needs ruby 1.9.3 while it is already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, ruby

I have problem installing paperclip gem in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

Activesupport complains that it needs `ruby 1.9.3` but I have it already installed.

```
root@Ubuntu-1204-precise-32-minimal /home/.../releases/current # gem install paperclip -v '3.3.1'
ERROR:  Error installing paperclip:
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.

root@Ubuntu-1204-precise-32-minimal /home/.../releases/current # ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby -S gem install paperclip -v '3.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [wojtek-b](https://serverfault.com/users/108814/wojtek-b) worked for me as I was trying to install `git_stats` and it was complaining about the same thing:

```
sudo ruby -S gem install git_stats
```

Tho I can't vote up the answer since I've just registered. But thanks [wojtek-b](https://serverfault.com/users/108814/wojtek-b)!